# Overriding Seaborn legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I made a line plot using seaborn's relplot and I wanted to customize my legend labels. For some reason when I do this, It creates another legend with out deleting the old one. How do I get rid of the initial legend (The legend with title "Sex")? Also how do I add a legend title to my new legend?

Here is the code I used to generate my plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))

sns.relplot(x='Year',y = 'cancer/100k pop' , data = dataset_sex,hue="Sex", kind="line",ci=None)
title_string = "Trend of Cancer incidencies by Sex " 
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.title(title_string)
plt.legend(['Men','Women'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regplot` is a figure-level function, and returns a `FacetGrid`. You can remove its legend via `g.legend.remove()`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day")
g.legend.remove()
plt.legend(['Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi', 'Dimanche'])
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

This code has been tested with seaborn 0.11. Possibly you'll need to upgrade. To add a title to the legend: `plt.legend([...], title='New title')`.

Note that `plt.legend(...)` will create the legend inside the last (or only) subplot. If you prefer the figure-level legend next to the plot, to change the legend labels, you can call `g.add_legend(labels=[...], title='new title')` after having removed the old legend.

PS: Adding `legend=False` to `sns.relplot()` will not create the legend entries. So, you'll need to recreate both the legend markers and their labels, while you lost the information of which colors were used.

Comment: Thank. you for your answer but the legend.remove() didn't work for me (It threw an error saying it doesn't exist). I did legend=False inside the parentheses instead and that worked.

Comment: Well, if you add `legend=False`, no entries are created for the legend, so you can't just change the labels (as asked in the question). With `legend=False`, you need to recreate not only the legend labels, but also the corresponding markers. `g.legend.remove()` could give an error in older Seaborn versions. In September 2020, version 0.11 has been released, for which this code has been tested.